# Python scopes and namespaces of imported modules

Tags: python, scope, namespaces

I am confused on how scopes and namespaces are determined in Python. Assuming I have a file system as following:

```
|-test1.py
 -test2.py
```

Each files is defined as below:

test1.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
def test1():
    print('test1')
```

test2.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from test1 import test1
def test2():
    test1()
    print('test2')
```

In python interactive interpreter, if I do the following:

```
import test2
test2.test2()
```

, the code would run fine and give following result:

```
test1
test2
```

From the output, we can see the interpreter can correctly identify the test1() function object. What confuses me is when  test1.test1 is imported during the execution? When this object goes into global scope?

Based on @Ziyad Edher answer, I have created a Venn diagram to illustrate the relationship of different scopes. Assumed the interpreter is replaced by a third file test3.py. Their scopes are as following: The circle represent the scope, the `File test3` refers to the `test3.py`, `File test2` refers to `test2.py`, `test2()` refers to the function `test2()` in the `test2.py`, `test1()` refers to the function `test1()` in the `test1.py`. The scope of `test2()` does not have `test1()`, so the interpreter would refer to a upper level scope `File test2`. The scope `File test2` has `test1()`, and calls it.

[image]

Comment: `test1` is only available within `test2` since that's where it's imported.

Comment: if u generally accept the comprehensive answer below, please click the green "check" icon shown on the left side of the answer to accept it and make a more inspiring open-source community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python module importing and global namespace management is a very broad topic, so I will limit this answer to the specific case that you are seeing.

In general, Python works very sequentially.

1. You open the interpreter, certain special values such as environment variable and other kernel variables are injected into the global namespace.
2. You execute `import test2`, this goes to the `test2.py` file in the local directory and executes that file in the same Python environment.
3. While executing `test2.py`, Python comes across `from test1 import test1`.
4. Similar to step 2, Python goes and finds `test1.py`, it does some extra things because you are importing a function in the module rather than the module itself, but in general, at this point, `test1` (the function) gets placed in the current scope.
5. You call `test2.test2()`, since `test2` has been imported in step 2, it exists and so does `test2.test2`. So the interpreter jumps to `test2.test2` and `test1` is called and since it is in namespace (we just imported it in step 3) no error is thrown, then your second print statement is called.

Things are obviously a bit more complicated than this on the low-level, but this does give a general overview of how Python deals with this stuff.

Comment: So function `test1` is in the scope of module/file `test2`, not in the scope of function `test2`. If a python file is imported as a module, then the import commands above all the classes/functions in this file is first executed. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It is nothing special with the fact that they are imports, it is just that Python executes the outermost layer of the file top-down. Hence why we usually place imports at the top (to have them be imported before anything else can run).

Comment: Thank you! I have created a Venn diagram to illustrate the idea. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Suppose the function makes use of variable 'a' which is only initialized in the calling module. Then can the function access this variable? Since the function definition and variable is present in global namespace of calling module. Or does the function still look at its own module namespace? For example: if the print(test1) was changed to print(a) and we declare a=10, then the function is called in the calling module. Will it use variable a from the calling module test2 or called module test1?